# cannot use the psql command with a user other than postgres

Tags: postgresql

So I created a user after installing postgres on my windows 10 computer to avoid using the main superuser, using:

`CREATE USER Blu LOGIN PASSWORD '<password>' CREATEDB;`

I then tried logging into psql using this account:

`psql -U Blu`

after giving it my password, I got greeted with this error:

`FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Blu"`

after looking around for an hour I found a lot of posts about this, all mentioning the pg_hba.conf file, except that all the things I've tried so far have failed to fix the issue

exemple of fixes I tried:

`local all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`

`local all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`

`local all Blu 127.0.0.1/32 md5`

`local all Blu 127.0.0.1/32 trust`

all of those failed since using local makes the config file fail to load

`host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident`
`host all Blu 127.0.0.1/32 ident`
`host <DBname> Blu 127.0.0.1/32 ident`

did all of those, no luck still

I'm now completely clueless on how to make this work for me, any ideas?

Comment: Your user is `blu` not `Blu`. If you want case sensitivity in SQL identifiers, you need to put double quotes around them.

Comment: yup, that was it, learn something new everyday, thanks a lot!